# Installing and using arm-none-eabi-gcc on MSYS2

Tags: c++, arm, msys2, gnu-toolchain, xpack

I am trying to build an embedded program using "make all" with the GNU ARM toolchain, but it is not working yet.

I installed it with xpm according to this website with the xpm installer:

https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/arm/install/

Now when I try to build my program using "make all", I get following error:

```
$ make all
```

> Collecting dependencies for: Bsp/....cpp
>   /bin/sh: Zeile 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found-
>   ...

The file is of course located in the xpack location:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\xPacks

while the normal mingw64 binaries are in another location. How exactly can I use arm-none-eabi-gcc now or how can I edit the PATH variables of msys2 to use the xpm packages?

There is also a similar toolchain here:

https://launchpad.net/~team-gcc-arm-embedded/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

But I guess I can not install this without something like Linux subsystem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloaded arm-none-eabi-gcc separately from MSYS2, then after starting your MSYS2 shell, you need to add whatever directory contains `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` to your PATH environment variable by running a command like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/path/to/bindir/
```

You can test it by running `arm-none-eabi-gcc` in the shell with no arguments, and also running `which arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

The main place to download such a toolchain is here:

https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain

Comment: Thank you. I used a similar solution: I edited the msys2_shell.cmd file in the msys64 directory and uncommented "set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit".
The path to the particular .exe was set in the windows path directory. I don't know if this is a clean solution but it worked for me.

Comment: Could a user with high-enough rep for a 1 character edit please change "argm-non-eabi-gcc" to "arm-non-eabi-gcc" in the above answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install `arm-none-eabi-gcc` on MSYS2 using its package manager.
Start MSYS2 using `mingw64.exe` (or the equivalent shortcut) and then install the toolchain by running:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

Now `arm-none-eabi-gcc` should be on your PATH without any additional work.